# Rails req location (MVC structure)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I'm a Rails newbie. Where do I put the following code - Where `name` is a folder in /models/name

```
req = Name.new
req.configure
```

Comment: I really tried, but i didn't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of logic should go in your Controller for this class (app/controllers/name).

For example:

```
def new
  @req = Name.new
  @req.configure

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @req }
  end
end
```

However there are commands you can run to set this all up automatically, more info at:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html